# How to check if there is a record in a SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code, what i am trying to achieve is that at first i want to check if there is a record based in the database according to a condition. if the record is there it should not do anything if the record is not in it should add it in.

```
if (context.dBconfig.Any(c => n.Name != "John")) // here i tried to check from the database if there is no records for john it should add in  the following.If it finds a record it shouldnt do an add.
{
    context.dBconfig.Add(       
        new List.dBconfig
        {
            Name = 'John',
            address = "test"
            contact = "test"
        }
    );
}
```

the problem is that everytime i run the above piece of code it does an entry for john when there is already an entry in. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `!Any(... == ...)` instead of `Any(... != ...)`:

```
if (!context.dBconfig.Any(c => n.Name == "John"))
{
  // ...
}
```

You are checking if there is someone who is *not John* instead of not someone who *is John*.